# Mongo lookup join on objectid not working?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For the collections:

```
 data:
 { "_id" : ObjectId("57a"), "rep" : ObjectId("570"), "label" : "pat" }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("57b"), "rep" : ObjectId("571"), "label" : "pat" }

 rep:
 { "_id" : ObjectId("570") }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("571") }
```

query

```
db.rep.aggregate([{ $lookup: 
   {from: "data", localField:"rep", foreignField:"_id", as: "in_common" }
}])
```

yields an empty set.

The query should produce a result with two rows.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13):

You need to modify your query as shown below

`db.data.aggregate([ { $lookup: {from: "rep", localField:"rep", foreignField:"_
id", as: "in_common" }}])`

This query will yield you two records.

**Reason for not getting the records**: In your collection you don't have mapping for data._id to rep._id whereas you have the mapping from rep._id to data.rep

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Thanks, that works. When actual ObjectId values are inserted, the query seems to return too many values. The query used was:  db.data.aggregate([ { $lookup: {from: "rep", localField:"ObjectId(_id)", foreignField:"ObjectId(rep)", as: "incommon"} }     ] )  Is searching for "ObjectId(_id)" against "ObjectId(rep)" correctly formatted?

Comment: That's great, please mark the question as answered so that it will be helpful to others who are facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and field mapping.